# How to clear cache Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I tried these commands:

```
php artisan config:cache  

php artisan route:cache  

php artisan cache:clear
```

All of them return me error:

```
Class 'App\Providers\InvitationServiceProvider' not found
```

But I dont have `InvitationServiceProvider` anywhere in project.

So, how to rebuild Laravel?

Also I tried `composer dump` and `php artisan serve`

Dump is:

```
PS C:\Projects\secure> composer dump-autoload -o
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'App\Providers\InvitationServiceProvider' not found


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan view:clear `

Comment: Have a look in `config/app.php` - you might have registered this in there. If not, have a look in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`. Once you find it, remove the reference to that and then run `composer dump-auto`

Comment: Could you post your `config/app.php` file?

Comment: Yes, later please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it
Make sure :

```
You have a file named InvitationServiceProvider inside App\InvitationServiceProvider.
The class InvitationServiceProvider is namespaced correctly.
You didn't change the app namespace.
```

//after that run the bellow comments

```
composer dump-autoload or composer update
```

Comment: there is no `App\Providers\InvitationServiceProvider` in app/php

Comment: sorry for the inconvinience,i have updated check it

Answer (score 4):

The correct name of the command is

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Don't know if you tried that one.

And also the service providers are usually registered within the `config\app.php` `providers` array, so take a look in that file and remove it from there too.

Or remove manually the `bootstrap\cache\packages.php` file.

EDIT:

From your dump it is obvious that you have the service provider registered in the config app file, so you tried to cache the config, try to clear the cache if you haven't tried the manual way yet:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

**I would really appreciate comments after someone downvotes an answer, this way I don't understand what is wrong in the answer.**

Comment: what about searching your whole project for occurance of `InvitationServiceProvider` because you obviously have it somewhere. Maybe you register it within another service provider like the `AppServiceProvider`.

Comment: had the same issue, tried everything but only removing the ./bootstrap/cache/config.php worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have tried registering your provider under 'providers' array of /app/cofig/app.php 
and then You have to do this do a 
`composer dump-autoload -o`